# Idioms or metaphors for "I'm curious to know why, but it seems I'll never know"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, metaphors

I had a technical issue and no one from customer service had any idea why it happened. But after a few days, my computer problem just got resolved mysteriously. I got too invested into the problem and now want to know why it happened, and why it got resolved. But there's no way to find out why, so I just have to live with that unsatisfied curiosity.

What are some ways to describe the feeling that I'll never know why? (not limited to only idioms or metaphors although it is preferred)

Thanks.

Comment: What are some phrases that you feel are close but do not fit?

Answer (score 2):

It was “one of life’s great mysteries”.

“something that is very difficult to understand”

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-one-another-of-life-s-great-mysteries)

The idiom often applies in a mildly humorous and gently deprecating way to small matters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved *inexplicably.*

Perhaps better, to focus on your feelings about the situation, you *resigned yourself to the inexplicable resolution.*

Metaphor:  *the problem left as mysteriously/inexplicably as it had arrived.*